# Flurry Analytics causing App Not Responding on Android App

Tags: android, analytics, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am trying to integrate flurry analytics in my Android App. I followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/).

However FlurryAgent.init is converting all App crashes into "App Not responding". For e.g. if any of the child activity has bug such as null pointer exception , as soon as I uncomment "FlurryAgent.init" instead of app crashing, app stops responding.

My flurry init code is in extended Application class and is properly setup in manifest file as well.

Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Comment: What version of Flurry? Are you using the `Jcenter` version or the jars?

Comment: I was using 6.3, yes jcenter version of the jars

Answer (score 1):

Contacted flurry support. Seems flurry 6.3 has bug about ANR and Flurry team is working on it. Used 6.2 and issue was resolved. Issue for 6.3 is for both compile dependency as well as jcenter jar files.